# App running fullscreen on iPhone 5 when it shouldn't

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm testing my app on iPhone 5 but something strange happened:

I'm developing for iOS 5.1 and the first times I was testing the app on the new iPhone 5 it was running normally. But suddenly it is running full screen! If i run the app on iPhone 4 inch simulator it appears as normal (not full screen).
In Build Settings the Deployment Target is 5.1. Though in the Summary a Launch Image space for  retina 4 inch has appeared and a warning that the image is missing.

How to make the app run "normal" (as 3,5 inch) on iPhone 5 again?

I'm using Xcode 4.5.1

Comment: Why do you want to do this, pray tell?

Comment: Xcode auto added the default-586h@2x.png to my project not supposed to run fullscreen on iPhone 5 yet. After removing the image, app still kept launching full screen. It messed up the layout of many of my views when running on 4inch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it:
If Xcode auto added image "default-586h@2x.png" to the project make sure it's properly deleted from project AND source folder. Then go Product --> Clean. Manually delete the application from simulator/iPhone. Build and run. Problem solved.

Comment: isn't that what I answered ? Delete the 4" splash resource. Why downvote ?

Comment: I removed the image from the summary view splash even before asking the question..

Comment: "remove" means remove from view AND the file itself, of course. Even if you don't add anything to the view but put the Default.png (and its derivates) to the app root they'll be taken by the system.
If you want a detailed answer try to show you don't understand the normal one first.

Comment: Get over it your answer just wasn't good enough in this case. Had to go Project -> Clean and delete project from device and re-build. Many others run into the same issue and I think they appreciate the full procedure of fixing it.

Comment: "not good enough" is not a reason to downvote, especially when its a subject of detail. The downvote mechanism here is for WRONG answers.
Well, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

just clean up the retina 4" splash from summary view

Comment: The only thing that got to do with retina 4" in the summary view is the space for the launch image and it says no image specified.. Nothing can be done except adding an image.

Comment: Isn't there some kind of setting for this somewhere in the build settings or something? I've seen through but couldn't find anything.